# mysql condition to ignore where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to execute a mysql query in joomla where it takes a variable in where clause with the first item in drop-down is please select. I can set the value of drop-down to any value.

myquery is like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$m = $db->getQuery(true);
$m="SELECT group_concat(distinct m.email
SEPARATOR ', ' ) FROM member m, email e 
where m.club_name='{email___club_email}' ";
$db->setQuery($m);
$a = $db->loadresult();
var_dump($a);exit;
return $a;
```

Now How I should put a clause in this query so that If I select "please select" then the where clause in the statement is ignored or I can get all the records in any other manner in the resultset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like `where m.club_name LIKE '{email___club_email}'"` and change the `value` of "please select" to `%` as the `%` is a wildcard in `MySQL`

Comment: Great. That is what I was looking for. I will accept your answer. When I had gone for accepting, I am getting a message that I can accept it in 9min.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something which is always true, like `WHERE 1 = 1`, which will return all records.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the value of the "please select" option as 0, and then do a simple if:

```
$m="SELECT group_concat(distinct m.email SEPARATOR ', ' ) FROM member m, email e"; 

if ($email) {
    $m .= " where m.club_name='{email___club_email}' ";
}
```